# Unity legacy line in middle of screen

Tags: unity-game-engine, legacy

[Image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffaZs.png)
I am trying to use the unity legacy text and there seems to be a line in the middle of the screen (X & Y axis) even when the scene is in game mode. Please help me remove it!

I tried toggling all of the settings but I couldn't find the right one. I also tried switching the view, but that didn't work either.

If none of this works should I try using the text-mesh-pro text? I'm still learning Unity so I do not know all of the UI features.

What I'm trying to do:
I am making an atom builder sim and I want to be able to change the number of particles while playing the game (after it is built).

Comment: turn off gizmos

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is happening is because you have gizmos on in the game view. To turn this off you just need to click on the "Gizmos" button on the top left corner of the window. If you still want gizmos to be on, and want to get rid of the line, just click the arrow pointing down right next to the "Gizmos" button then search for "Canvas" then make sure the toggle is not toggled.